# Swift: Array of Dictionaries get nested value

Tags: swift

I'm need help in Swift, hope someone here can help me, I'm new and I don't understand exactly how to get values out of a nested JSON.
this is what I have. In the example bellow I need to get "fullName" value out of this array can someone explain how would that work. I need to add it to and UILable. I really appreciate any help possible. thank you.  Error is No exact match in call to superscript

```
    let worf : Array<NSDictionary> = [[
    "credentials": "<null>",
    "facultyImage": "https://cdn.atpoc.com",
    "fullName":"Deepak L. Bhatt, MD, MPH",
    "jobAffiliations": "Executive Director<br />Interventional Cardiovascular Programs<br />Brigham and Women&#8217;s Hospital<br />Heart &amp; Vascular Center<br />Professor of Medicine<br />Harvard Medical School<br />Boston, Massachusetts",
    "role": "Faculty"
]
  ,[
    "credentials": "<null>",
    "facultyImage": "https://cdn.atpoc.com",
    "fullName":"Javed Butler, MD, MPH",
    "jobAffiliations": "Professor of Medicine<br />Department of Medicine<br />University of Mississippi Medical Center<br />Jackson, Mississippi",
    "role": "Faculty"
  ]]

let myLists = [worf]

var myArray = [String]()
if let answersData = myLists["fullName"] as? String {
    for i in 0 ..< answersData.count{
        let result = answersData.values
        myArray.append(result)
    }
}
print("favorite drink:", myArray)
facultyCredentialsText.text = myArray.joined(separator: "\n")
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KkdiR.png)

Comment: Why are you adding the Array of dictionaries in another array?

Answer (score 2):

There are some pretty serious mistakes:

- `worf` is already an array `[worf]` makes it *worse* by adding another level.
- You cannot subscript (not ***super***-) an array.
- `fullName` is a string, a loop makes no sense unless you want to iterate the **characters**.

And **never** use `NSDictionary` in Swift unless the compiler tells you to do it in some CoreFoundation APIs. Without the type annotation the compiler infers the array as `[[String:STring]]` which avoids the conditional downcast to `String`.

To get an array of all `fullName`s use something like

```
let worf = [[ ... ]]

let myArray = worf.compactMap{$0["fullName"]}
print("favorite drink:", myArray)
// avorite drink: ["Deepak L. Bhatt, MD, MPH", "Javed Butler, MD, MPH"]
```